# creen even when the window screen size is

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to keep the left sidebar that you see on this [page here][1] when the window size is 970px. Right now, if I make this window size 970 px, the left sidebar disappears. How do I keep the sidebar on the page even at 970px breakpoint?

[![snapshot of side bar even][2]][2]

```
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: first at all, dont use float for ytling a website. Its not only outdated but also was never the intended use for it. I'm aware that it is mis-used by many and tought in some poor tutorials. Float should only be used to float images within a text paragraph. For everything else either use flexboxes or css-grid.

Answer (score 2):

The sidebar is there on the bottom but it has been set to `display none;` You should just remove the lines 55 - 58 in your **assets/prebuild/css/partials/_responsive2015-mobileTablet.scss** and the sidebar will appear at the end

[image]
[image]

---

**EDIT**

After some clarification here is the updated answer. If you can separate the pages that need to have the sidebar active then you should add an extra class either on your body tag or in the .leftNav2 container. Meaning:

```
<body style="position: relative; min-height: 100%; top: 0px;" class="with-sidebar">
```

and then on your mediaQuery

```
/*Department Left Nav*/
.department nav .leftNav2,
.department nav #leftNav {
     display:none;
}
.with-sidebar .department nav .leftNav2,
.with-sidebar .department nav #leftNav {
     display:block;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225392/discussion-on-answer-by-aristeidis-karavas-how-do-i-keep-the-left-sidebar-on-scr).